# Calculate minimum readable textSize for Android tablets & tv devices

Tags: android, resolution, font-size, tablet, android-tv

For Android Tv, [Android recommends](http://developer.android.com/design/tv/style.html)  Designing your artwork assets for best viewing at HD resolution (1920 x 1080 pixels).

There are following two available resolutions for TVs:

- 1280x720
- 1920x1080

Main two screen sizes available for android Tablets are 7 inch & 10 inch. This incurs in following two key resolutions(Considered from [here](http://www.binvisions.com/articles/tablet-smartphone-resolutions-screen-size-list/)):

- 7” tablets: 1024x600
- 10” tablets: 1280x800

Also, for different display devices we can have different resolution for Android TV devices and for tables for also.

I needs to calculate minimum readable `textSize` for each device for given message of given length.

Lets give me an example, User sets maximum message length to `n chars`. Now, I want to restrict user for this character length for specific device. So that i can have maximum length of message with minimum `fontSize` that is readable to users for all TV & tablet devices. It would be fine if we have lower limit, but maximum character limit should not make TextView scroll-able.

Initially I tried to calculate maximum message length as per `fontSize` of textview like following:

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int dens = dm.densityDpi;
    double wi = (double) width / (double) dens;
    double hi = (double) height / (double) dens;
    double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

  //long charLimit = (long) (Math.pow(Math.floor((dens / 18)), 2) * 2);
    long charLimit = (long) (((Math.floor((dens / 26)) * wi) * (Math.floor((dens / 26)) * hi)) / (wi + hi));
  //long charLimit = (long) ((Math.floor((dens / 22)) * Math.floor((x + y)) * 2));
    String msg = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < charLimit; i++) {
        msg += "A";
    }
    text.setText(msg);

    Log.e("screenInches", "screenInches: " + screenInches + " width:" + width + "/" + wi + " height:" + height + "/" + hi + " densityDpi:" + dens + " charLimit:" + charLimit);
```

But couldn't get satisfied results. Now,All what i want is to calculate minimum readable `fontSize` (say S), for given length(say n char) of message to be displayed without scroll on both Tv and tablet devices.

I know font-family and font-style also affects this. But considering system default configurations which are proper approaches, I should follow?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on how far he's sitting away from the TV and whether he's wearing glasses or not?

Comment: May be, but the minimum recommended font size for TV is 12sp.The default text size setting should be 18sp. We may take 18sp as benchmark for TVs. Check: http://developer.android.com/design/tv/style.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I remember by GoogleTV days.

Comment: Yes, there can be lots of possibilities. but with some limitations we can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do very well with variable-width fonts. Each character I'm writing has a different width and this means each character's width has to be computed separately. A monospace font would be easier to compute.